# Why does Django return X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN from views decorated with xframe_options_exempt?

Tags: django, csrf, clickjacking

I have a Django view decorated with `@xframe_options_exempt`, and I'm hosting it in an `iframe`. The `GET` request on the view works fine, but the `POST` results in a browser error because the response comes back with `X-Frame-Options` set to `SAMEORIGIN`.

Why isn't `@xframe_options_exempt` working?

Answer (score 0):

If an exception occurs during the handling of the `POST` request, then the `@xframe_options_exempt` decorator won't have a chance to do it's thing. So if this is happening to you, look for an exception.

In my case, I had a bug in my app code that I had to fix **plus** I was getting CSRF exceptions because my `iframe` was hosted by another domain. I had to add the following settings to get it working, which I gleaned from a few different StackOverflow posts:

```
# CSRF
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
    '.mysite1.com',
    '.mysite2.com',
    ...
]
CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE = None
```

`CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS` allows you to continue to use CSRF protection as long as your `iframe` is hosted by a trusted site. The dots in front of the domains mean subdomains are allowed.

`CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE = None` allows the CSRF cookie to be sent across sites.

See the [Django Settings documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/) for more information.